# Every time I print a list, it prints the elements 2 times. How can I prevent that from happening?

Tags: python, list, networking, printing

```
import os
from netaddr import *
import sys
import socket
from pprint import pprint
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools
import bisect

    ip_list = []
    server_list = []
    while True:
        try:
            server = (input('> '))
            if server == 'q':
                break
            ip_addr = socket.gethostbyname(server)
        except socket.gaierror:
            print(server, 'can\'t find server/ip', '\n')

        ip_list.append(ip_addr)
        server_list.append(server)
        print(ip_list)
```

Output (I am inputting 2 servers in this case and returning 2 IPs):

```
['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2']
```

Now when I insert that list into the overall purpose of the script it prints out the list twice.
For simplicity's sake, 'network' pulls up a list of subnets/routes but I am leaving that code out due to it being irrelevant to the issue at hand.

```
    for ip_address in ip_list:
        if IPAddress(ip_address) in IPNetwork(network):
            print(ip_address)
```

Output:

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
```

How can I make the addresses print once instead of twice?

Comment: Move print out of loop.

Comment: What are IPAddress and  IPNetwork ? Classes ?

Comment: @OlvinRoght what do you mean move print out of the loop? If i do so, I get an indentation error.

Comment: Did you intend to add servers that can't be found to the list? You have `ip_list.append(ip_addr)` outside the `try`, so it will be done even after an error.

Comment: so i found that i am getting two entries on the output because 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2 return and print the default route out @ 0.0.0.0/0 and they also return the route 10.0.0.0/24. I am wondering how I would be able to exclude the default route out without having it exclude every time because of edge cases where that 0.0.0.0/0 would apply

Answer (score 0):

Do `print(ip_list)` after the loop is done, so you only print it once, not after each time you append to it.

Also, you should append to the lists inside the `try`. Otherwise, when you get an error, you'll still append the server, and also append the address of the *previous* server.

```
ip_list = []
server_list = []
while True:
    try:
        server = (input('> '))
        if server == 'q':
            break
        ip_addr = socket.gethostbyname(server)
        ip_list.append(ip_addr)
        server_list.append(server)
    except socket.gaierror:
        print(server, 'can\'t find server/ip', '\n')

print(ip_list)
print(server_list)
```

Comment: I would use `else` block for appending lists, what do you think?